# JavaScript-text input validation not work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" >
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm " name="s">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default ">submit</button>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="">back</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

i try to do validation with JavaScript,but my JavaScript is not work. The form will submit without validation.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var x = document.forms["input"]["s"].value;
            if(x == null || x == "") {
                alert('Please enter something!');
                return false;
            }
            else 
                return confirm('confirm submit?');
        }
 </script>
```

How can i fix the problem?

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zh6tLggz/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the order of form in document. orders start from 0. also modify the input address as below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var x = document.forms[0].s.value;
            if(x == null || x == "") {
                alert('Please enter something!');
                return false;
            }
            else 
                return confirm('confirm submit?');
        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.forms["input"]
```

Looks for a form named input, but your form has no name. Add

```
name="input"
```

To your form tag. If the handler function has an error then the form is submitted, which is a non intuitive behavior, imho.

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms` is a `HTMLCollection`. Its named items' names are the id or name of a node. Your form has neither the id "input" nor the name "input", so `document.forms["input"]` doesn't return it.